# how to remove every n block of rows after every mth row?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a data file like this :

```
0000 0f 13 45 54 23 24 ae e1 f6
0001 f8 31 35 23 24 e7 e6 e1 f5
0002 0f 13 45 54 23 24 ae e1 f6
0003 0f 13 45 54 23 24 ae e1 f6
0004 f8 31 35 23 24 e7 e6 e1 f5
0005 0f 13 45 54 23 24 ae e1 f6 
0006 0f 13 45 54 23 24 ae e1 f6
```

So let's say i would like to remove every 2nd 3rd row starting from top and leaving 2 rows each after which the output should be:

```
0000 0f 13 45 54 23 24 ae e1 f6
0003 0f 13 45 54 23 24 ae e1 f6
0004 f8 31 35 23 24 e7 e6 e1 f5
```

Comment: It looks like you want: out of each group of 4 lines, keep the first and the fourth.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '2~4,+1d' file
```

Start at line 2 and modulo 4 thereafter, remove 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -ne 'print if $. % 4 < 2' file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line;
- `$.` contains the current line number;
- `%` is the modulo operator, the formula here selects lines 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, etc. which is what we need.

Comment: Maybe I put the question wrong way I have a file like :
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
ad13
ada14
dad15
adasfd16
adw17
d18
ada19
wdd20
aa21
dwd22
wa23
dawd24
adadwa25
wdadww26
dwad27
wda28  
I would like to remove lines 4,5,6  10,11,12  16,17,18 ...

Comment: Please, update the question. Try to explain how one should identify the lines to keep or remove.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to remove lines 4,5,6 10,11,12 16,17,18

First we need to express that using in terms of remainder of division, you want to jettison lines where remainder from division by 6 is 4 or 5 or 0 this might be expressed in GNU `AWK` following way, let file.txt content be

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

then

```
awk 'NR%6!=4&&NR%6!=5&&NR%6!=0' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1
2
3
7
8
9
13
14
15
19
20
```

Explanation: `NR` is number of row, `%` remainder from division, `&&` logical and, I am selected line where remainder from division of number of row by 6 is not 4 and is not 5 and is not 0. If you want to know more about `NR` read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` command should do the trick:

```
sed -n 'p;n;n;n;p' file
```